# Execute code before leaving function

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am currently working on some code for an `sqlite` database. I noticed that after preparing a query, I would always need to finalize the query (`sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)`) before I exit the function. Is there a way to do this other than fill in all the possibilities?

For example:

```
func updateColumn(db: COpaquePointer, name: String, x: sqlite3_int64, y: String!=nil) -> Bool {
    var statement = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET X=?"
    var statementPointer: COpaquePointer = nil
    if y != nil {
        statement += ", Y=?"
    }
    statement += " WHERE NAME=?"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statement, -1, &statementPointer, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        return false
    } else if sqlite3_bind_int64(statementPointer, 1, x) != SQLITE_OK {
        // Note this code here
        sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
        return false
    }

    if y != nil {
        if sqlite3_bind_text(statementPointer, 2, y, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            // Note this repetition
            sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
            return false
        }
    }

    if sqlite3_step(statementPointer) != SQLITE_DONE {
        // Note this repetition
        sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
        return false
    }
    // Note this repetition
    sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
    return true
}
```

Of course, this is just something I came up to illustrate this. In the real code, there are many other `if` clauses which I need to finalize their statements.

I understand that this is something like `deinit` for classes in swift but are there `deinit`s for functions as well?

For example (code that I would like it to be like but doesn't work):

```
func updateColumn(params...) -> Bool {
    // code...
    deinit {
        sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a "deinit for functions" — it's called [`defer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/defer-statement):

> A `defer` statement is used for executing code just before transferring program control outside of the scope that the `defer` statement appears in.

Note that unlike your hypothetical example, the `defer` statement must appear *before* whatever might happen to cause the cleanup it performs, not at the end of the enclosing scope. In general, it works like this:

```
func doStuff() {
    let resource = acquireResource()
    defer {
        cleanup(resource)
    }
    if something { return }
    doOtherStuff()
}
```

Here, `cleanup(resource)` gets called regardless of whether the function exits because of `if something` or because it reaches the end of its scope (after `doOtherStuff()`).

You can't put a `defer` inside an `if` like you're  asking -- it only defers to the exit of the scope it's in, so it'd execute at the end of the `if` body. But `defer` does compose well with `guard`... In your case, you probably want something like this:

```
func updateColumn(db: COpaquePointer, name: String, x: sqlite3_int64, y: String!=nil) -> Bool {
    var statementPointer: COpaquePointer = nil
    //... Other stuff...

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statement, -1, &statementPointer, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        else { return false }
    // after this you want any possible exit to do finalize, so put the defer here
    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer) }

    // every `return` after here, true or false, will execute the `defer` clause
    guard sqlite3_bind_int64(statementPointer, 1, x) == SQLITE_OK 
        else { return false }

    guard y != nil && sqlite3_bind_text(statementPointer, 2, y, -1, nil) == SQLITE_OK 
        else { return false }

    guard sqlite3_step(statementPointer) == SQLITE_DONE 
        else { return false }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about to use [defer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-defer) keyword.

```
func updateColumn(params...) -> Bool {
    // code...
    defer {
        sqlite3_finalize(statementPointer)
    }
}
```